# RaycastHit Randomly Gets 2 Hits

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been following a tutorial online for a while and so far its gone pretty well. The only problem I have is with RaycastHit. Now at first glance everything seems to be working pretty well, but every now and then it seems as if I get two hits. Basically I have it set up so that every time I press the mouse button, an animation will go off with the player swinging a club and a ray will be sent from the player(actually a gameObject parented by the first person camera) to the enemy. But sometimes instead of the gameObject being destroyed in two hits, every now and then, its destroyed in only one.

```
#pragma strict

var TheDamage : int = 50;
var Distance : float;           
var MaxDistance : float = 1.5;
var TheSystem : Transform;


function Update ()                               
{
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) 
{   
animation.Play("Attack"); 
}
}

function AttackDamage () 
{
var hit : RaycastHit;
if(Physics.Raycast (TheSystem.transform.position, TheSystem.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward),hit))
{                                            
Distance = hit.distance; 
}       
if (Distance < MaxDistance)
{                                       
EnemyLogic.ApplyDamage(TheDamage);
}
}
```

&&

```
#pragma strict

static var Health = 100;

function Update ()
{
if (Health <= 0)
{
Dead ();
}
}

static function ApplyDamage (TheDamage: int)
{
Health -= TheDamage;
}

function Dead ()
{
Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Comment: This may or may not be related: Move the `if (Distance < MaxDistance)` block inside of the `if(Physics.Raycast...` block, otherwise `AttackDamage` will apply damage to your enemy based on whether or not the last hit was successful.  If `Physics.Raycast` is false (no hit), your code still tests if `Distance` is within range but the value of `Distance` is that of the last successful hit.

Comment: Ok your right, looks like that did it. Thats a little tricky. Thank you for the help

Comment: Just one more quick question. Why would the AttackDamage apply damage to the enemy regardless of whether or not the hit was successful? Isn't that the point of RaycastHit? If a hit wasn't made then the var shouldn't have any information in the first place right? So then how could it even be used in the other if statement so that damage is applied?

Comment: You should either make `Distance` a local variable (with some negative initial value) or reset it if `Physics.Raycast` failed (again to some negative value)